# Roland KR-370 Sound

Tags: digital-piano

I have a Roland KR-370 Japanese version. The speakers work when I plug my phone into the microphone jack, but the sound from the piano itself doesn't go through to the speakers or earphones.

I checked for blown fuses and loose wires, but can't see anything like that. I checked the setting for Local Control and it's on, as it should be. I tried all the other troubleshooters in the manual, but nothing worked.

I noticed the volume and balance sliders have no effect on the volume of the music when I played it through my phone. I don't know if that would help in diagnosing the problem.

I live in Phnom Penh, Cambodia, so it's difficult to find technicians. Could any one of you possibly help me out? Give me ideas on what the problem could be? Maybe you've seen something like this before?

I would appreciate that very much! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If your keyboard has two 1/4-inch line outputs labeled L/Mono and R (left/mono and right), you need two cables that have male mono 1/4-inch plugs on one end and male RCA plugs on the other.

If your keyboard has a single stereo 1/8-inch jack (labeled as an output), you need a special type of Y cable that has a male stereo 1/8-inch plug on one end and splits out into two cables with male RCA plugs.

If your keyboard offers no jack labeled as an output, you can use the headphone jack to connect to your stereo. If it’s a 1/4-inch jack, you need a cable with a male stereo 1/4-inch plug on one end that breaks out into two male RCA plugs on the other. This Y cord is readily available in musical instrument stores and online.

When you’re armed with the correct cables, here’s how to connect them:

- Make sure both devices are turned off and their volumes set to 0.
- Connect the L output of your keyboard to the L AUX In and the R output of
  your keyboard to the R AUX In.
- Turn on the keyboard first, waiting until it has fully powered up before moving on.
- Set your home stereo to AUX and then power it on.
- Bring the keyboard’s volume up to around 50 percent.

Comment: Thanks for that informative reply, Cheche! I will probably come back to that info in future. Perhaps I didn't make it clear that it's the onboard speakers of the piano that are not receiving signal from the piano sound card or whatever sends the sound to the onboard speakers. I did manage to eventually find a technician, so next week I will probably have more answers...  Thanks again for your time and effort (and knowledge sharing). It is much appreciated! 